# AS3 memory leak

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I've been working on a library, and have run into a problem with application memory.

I created a class called *FileManager* which allows the user to call a function called `loadNewFiles` - this function opens a multi-file selection dialog and stores each *FileReferenceList* in a vector. I can call the `removeList` function at any time and remove that list and clear any memory and listeners allocated to that list, so all's well there.

I created another class called *UploadManager*, which takes an array of *FileReference* objects and uploads them to a URL via the `uploadFiles` function. The memory leak appears to be here. When you call this function, it adds the appropriate event listeners and calls the upload function. If the upload fails or the upload is finished, it removes the listeners and clears the vector it has been waiting in.

after the upload manager finishes uploading the files, I call the `removeFiles` function in *FileManager* (which, remember, worked perfectly before) and... Nothing happens. The files are removed from both vectors, the listeners are removed from both files, but the memory stays allocated. This obviously has potential to cause problems along the road, as there's no limit to the number of files, uploads, etc. available through the library.

classes:
[FileManager](https://github.com/egg82/GTLib/blob/dev/src/org/gametack/file/FileManager.as)
[UploadManager](https://github.com/egg82/GTLib/blob/dev/src/org/gametack/file/UploadManager.as)

[Implementation](http://github.com/egg82/GTLib/blob/dev/src/Main.as)

Comment: How are you confirming that the memory stays allocated to these objects? If you are using the profiler in Flash Builder it can tell you what is keeping references to any objects it finds loitering in memory.

Comment: @SunilD. - thanks for the reply, i'm using FlashDevelop as my IDE.
for stats, i'm using a custom stats profile I made, forked from the Hi-Res stats github repo.

Comment: This allocation may be temporary... try to repeat the tests and check if it rises constantly.

Comment: 1000 lines of code... Can not run the example [missing definitions of Stats, DownloadManager, Signal, CustomFileReference, CustomFileReferenceList]. Kind of hard to get something sustainable in this scenario since the memory issue might as well be related to any of the other implementations that still holds some memory. Might be that you only run System.gc() once, not twice when you check memory. Bazillion things that could be the cause of this and with no running example it's kind of impossible to tell what the real issue is...

Comment: oh, sorry about that. All definitions are part of the library, so downloading the full library would work. However, I don't expect that. Imports should tell you where each missing file is. The reason I was able to localize the memory issue to *UploadManager* is because the exact amount of heap memory used by *FileManager* remains after *UploadManager* finishes its task. It's hard to argue that some archaic class uses several hundred MB of heap memory (in the case of uploading a movie file, which I tested) - I never run `System.gc()` in any of my library classes.

Comment: @loxxy - thanks for the post, it shed some light on other projects I (and others I know) have been working on that slowly consume memory. I think this has something to do with it, and it's interesting to say the least. If I load in a full movie, then immediately remove it, it removes all memory associated with that object. However, if it persists and is linked to by another object (that I know of for sure) it seems to hang on to (at least) the memory, even if the object is unlinked and removed from the AS3-level (rendering me unable to use it ever again) - more testing is required.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like from your example that the UploadManager still has a reference to the files either from the vector passed into uploadFiles, or some other object in the game still has a reference.

Also note, System.gc() only works on the debug version of the flash player.

So you can't depend on it for an architectural design choice. It works for unit testing memory intensive operations when you need to see the consumption of ActionScript memory "on demand".

In a production product, the ActionScript Virtual Machine is very active in detecting when and where to garbage collect. Most would say it happens right when you don't want it to.

Try profiling the application and looking at the "cumulative instances" vs. "instances", as well as the "cumulative memory" vs. "memory" for the objects in question (i.e. FileReference).

You can force garbage collection during runtime in the Profile View to get a realistic idea of how much memory is actually freed when garbage collection takes place in the Release version.